# How would you compare the value of element.getAttribute() to a String in protractor?

Tags: typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, protractor

Using protractor and typescript, I want to be able to compare the resulting value of `element.getAttribute("value")` to a string to verify the text in a textbox was successfully saved. `getText()` does not work in this scenario because the text entered into the field (editable textbox) is not saved as a text attribute of the element. Here is my method:

```
  async getName(option) {
    if(option == this.name.getAttribute("value").toString()){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This always returns false, even when passing the correct value. However I know `name.getAttribute("value")` is returning the correct value because when I output the result to the console, it is displaying the correct value.

When I type `option` from the above method as a `string` it gives me the following error: `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'String' and '() => string' have no overlap.ts(2367)`. I am assuming this has something to do with protracor returning promises, but I am unsure of any other way to compare the text to the expected value.

Edit: I should also note that I attempted this in another way too, where the method just returned the result of `name.getAttribute("value")` and then compared the result to the string I was expecting rather than doing it all in the method and expecting it to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAttribute` will return a promise so it should be resolved to capture value, we should be able to verify this using below

`expect(this.name.getAttribute("value")).toEqual('bar');`

if you want to get value and assign it to another variable you can use

```
this.name.getAttribute("value").then(function (value) {
    foo = vale
});
```

Answer (score 0):

be consistent when debugging.

1. `.getAttribute("value")` returns promise
2. Promise is an object
3. Object.toString() returns `"[object Object]"`
4. in the end you compare `"[object Object]"` with lets say `"result"` which is always `false`

To fix this, don't forget to resolve the Promise. don't try to put everything in one line, this makes your code not readable and not debbugable. By the way, `.getAttribute("value")` return String anyway, no need to call `toString()`. And don't use `==`, always go with `===` (my conclusion after 4 years of experience doing automation)

Use this

```
async getName(option) {
  let value = await this.name.getAttribute("value")
  if(option === value){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
// or even better
async getName(option) {
  let value = await this.name.getAttribute("value")
  return option === value
}
```

But still, your code is confusing. Why? Because your method named get name, but the returned value is not a name at all, it returns boolean. So better be explicit, for example `nameEqualsValue` of something like this